# Log4net to variable files

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net, log4net-appender

I need to create per-user log - amount of logged data will be significant and I don't want to keep it in a single file.

Is there a way to configure log4net in such way, that I'll be able to specify, which file log should be written to?

Surely, I can write my own appender. But how to pass to it (nicely) information about the destination file?

Comment: Why not log to a database and store the username as part of the entry?

Answer (score 1):

If your filename does not change during program execution, then you can initialise it

```
string logfileName = ...

log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = logfileName;
```

Note, this needs to be done **before** the first message is logged.

Then change your config file to use this property, eg

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogName}" />
    ...
```

You can use the built in variables like ${USERNAME} and or ${COMPUTERNAME} in the pattern string .

eg

```
 <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="LogFileFor_${USERNAME}_On_${COMPUTERNAME}.log" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it *will* change during program execution, logging is being performed in the service, which works for different users simultaneously.